# Getting app:dexDebug error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is my full app.gradle file used in the application

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.album"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile project('libraries:library')
    compile project('libraries:animation_library')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_0_6_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-5.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile project(':app:libraries:ExpandableLibrary')
    compile project(':app:libraries:library_appintro')
    compile project(':app:libraries:library_circular_loading:library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile project(path: ':Push Notification', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

and always get error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: does this version installed in ur sk manager ?minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: Yes, I have installed, It was working fine before some days. But Now, after adding some dependencies its getting error

Comment: change buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2" to buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

Comment: @ranjith. Just try to clean and build your project again.I think it will solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, 
Its already described in Android WEbLineindia's answer, But some add-ons required.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.album"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and in dependencies

```
// highest version available
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and in your application class

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In default config add this :

```
defaultConfig{
                multiDexEnabled = true
            }
```

And in same build.gradle add :

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

And in dependencies add :

```
 dependencies
{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

This Might Help You !

Comment: @ Android Weblineindia ,  I will try. 
In dependencies, is it necessary to add other libs/ dependency projects

Comment: By using this "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" , it might not require but you can double check for your included lib/dependencies. But you need to include multidex:1.0.0

Comment: I have tried this "mutidex" method but its crashing in kitkat devices,

getting error "NoclassDefFoundError"

Comment: I am using floatingEditText and getting inflating exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.me.album.R$styleable